# javascript for adobe acrobat form

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Trying to write script for adobe acrobat xi form
When the user selects checkbox7 the field should display a value of 239 and if it is unchecked it shows a value of 0 
Also I have it set to mouse up (is that correct?)
 Below is my code:

```
var Checkbox7Value = this.getField("Checkbox7");
if (Checkbox7Value.isBoxChecked(239))
var Checkbox7Value = 239
else
var Checkbox7Value = 0
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: **first:** tell us what your code does or which errors you are getting. why are you asking **us** if  your code is correct? why don't you just try it? **second:** afaik adobe javascript code is old stuff that's very poorly supported and documented. I messed around with it a bit and it's a pain in the ...

Comment: No data shows in field when I check or uncheck the checkbox7   (which when checked exports as "Yes" not sure if that makes a difference).

Comment: @low_rents: I will send you a few nails from France… (to replenish what you don't have, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

What is the return value of the checkbox? Is it the default "Yes", or anything else?

However, the code is pretty much messed up, I must say…

In the first line, you define a Field Object, linked to the field Checkbox7

In the second line you test whether the 239th widget/occurrence of that field is checked.

Depending on the result, you redefine the Field Object as a number.

Anyways, assuming that you don't have that many calculations, and dependencies, and that the return value of the checkbox field is indeed "Yes", you would add the following to the Calculate event of the field where the result shall appear:

```
if (this.getField("Checkbox7").value == "Yes") {
event.value = 239 ;
} else {
event.value = 0 ;
}
```

Now if you know that checking the Checkbox7 field will always mean "239", you can set its return value to 239, and then the code becomes even simpler:

```
event.value = this.getField("Checkbox7").valueAsString.replace(/Off/gim, "0") ;
```

We have to do the replace() because the value for "unchecked" is always "Off" in a checkbox/radiobutton.